# sonar-runner.bat issues when use H2 database

Tags: configuration, sonarqube

I download sonar-3.5.1 from the sonar web site. and i set the sonar.properties database  like this:

```
sonar.jdbc.username:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.password:                       sonar
sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.h2.Driver
sonar.embeddedDatabase.port:               9092
```

Then i deploy sonar to Tomcat. I can browse it from the `http://xxzjjc:8080/sonar`.
Then i start to run the analyse sonar-runner.bat. but error occured:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to connect to database
ERROR: Caused by: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
ERROR: Caused by: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried this for one day, but unfortunately, I didn't find any thing. Can anybody give me a solution? thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

If you configure your Sonar instance to be working with H2 DB (which is the default configuration by the way), you must set up the same configuration on the Sonar Runner side.

From what I see in the log excerpt that you copied, you have defined other settings - either in `<sonar_runner_home>/conf/sonar-runner.properties` file or in the `sonar-project.properties` file of your project. So you need to change them to reflect the ones set in your Sonar instance.